# How to use IEnumerable.GroupBy comparing multiple properties between elements?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I group "adjacent" Sites:

Given data:

```
List<Site> sites = new List<Site> {
    new Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=0.00m, EndMilepost=1.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=1.00m, EndMilepost=2.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=5.00m, EndMilepost=7.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=3.00m, EndMilepost=5.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=11.00m, EndMilepost=13.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=13.00m, EndMilepost=14.00m },
};
```

I want result:

```
[
    [
        Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=0.00m, EndMilepost=1.00m },
        Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=1.00m, EndMilepost=2.00m }
    ],
    [
        Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=5.00m, EndMilepost=7.00m }
    ],
    [
        Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=3.00m, EndMilepost=5.00m }
    ],
    [
        Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=11.00m, EndMilepost=13.00m },
        Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=13.00m, EndMilepost=14.00m }
    ]
]
```

I tried using GroupBy with a custom comparer function checking routeIds match and first site's end milepost is equal to the next sites start milepost. My HashKey function just checks out routeId so all sites within a route will get binned together but I think the comparer makes an assumption like if A = B, and B = C, then A = C, so C won't get grouped with A,B,C since in my adjacency case, A will not equal C.

Comment: You have to use one of [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) with custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: Not sure i got the point so i write a comment before answering: what you need to do is: `sites.GroupBy(x => x == "fooo").ThenBy(x => x == "fooo2")`? (`using System.Linq` is needed)

Comment: The problem is your relationship ISN'T transative, ie A~B and B~C !=> A~C for any operation ~ that doesn't already 'know' about the existence of B.  You should NOT try to hack something that works via LINQ GroupBy (which is an equality grouping) but add your own operation that encompasses this behavior.

Comment: A question asking how to actually perform the bucketing with an efficient algorithm/object is a perfectly valid, and interesting, question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised that `GroupBy` doesn't have overload with `Func<..., bool>` for in-place grouping without hassle of implementing custom class.

So I've created one:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> func)
{
    var items = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (items.Count != 0)
            if (!func(items[0], item))
            {
                yield return items;
                items = new List<T>();
            }
        items.Add(item);
    }
    if (items.Count != 0)
        yield return items;
}
```

The usage:

```
var result = sites.GroupBy((x, y) => x.RouteId == y.RouteId &&
    x.StartMilepost <= y.EndMilepost && x.EndMilepost >= y.StartMilepost).ToList();
```

This should produce wanted result.

Few words about implementation. In above extension method you have to supply delegate which should return true if `x` and `y` should be grouped. The method is dumb and will simply compare adjacent items in same order as they come. Your input is ordered, but you may have to use `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` before using it with something else.

Comment: This is closer to what I was imagining. Thanks! This reminds me of using Python's itertools.groupby and a comparer as keyfunc

Answer (score 3):

First, let `Site` class be (for debugging / demonstration)

```
public class Site {
  public Site() { }

  public string RouteId;
  public Decimal StartMilepost;
  public Decimal EndMilepost;

  public override string ToString() => $"{RouteId} {StartMilepost}..{EndMilepost}";
}
```

Well, as you can see we have to **break the rules**: equality must be *transitive*, i.e. whenever

```
A equals B
B equals C
```

then

```
A equals C
```

It's not the case in your example. However, if we *sort* the sites by `StartMilepost` we, technically, can implement `IEqualityComparer<Site>` like this:

```
public class MySiteEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Site> {
  public bool Equals(Site x, Site y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    else if (null == x || null == y)
      return false;
    else if (x.RouteId != y.RouteId)
      return false;
    else if (x.StartMilepost <= y.StartMilepost && x.EndMilepost >= y.StartMilepost)
      return true;
    else if (y.StartMilepost <= x.StartMilepost && y.EndMilepost >= x.StartMilepost)
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Site obj) {
    return obj == null
      ? 0
      : obj.RouteId == null
         ? 0
         : obj.RouteId.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

then `GroupBy` as usual; please, note that `OrderBy` is required, since order of comparision *matters* here. Suppose we have

```
A = {RouteId="X", StartMilepost=0.00m, EndMilepost=1.00m}
B = {RouteId="X", StartMilepost=1.00m, EndMilepost=2.00m}
C = {RouteId="X", StartMilepost=2.00m, EndMilepost=3.00m}
```

Here `A == B`, `B == C` (so in case of `A, B, C` all items will be in the same group) but `A != C` (and thus in `A, C, B` will end up with `3` groups)

**Code:**

```
 List<Site> sites = new List<Site> {
    new Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=0.00m, EndMilepost=1.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=1.00m, EndMilepost=2.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="A", StartMilepost=5.00m, EndMilepost=7.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=3.00m, EndMilepost=5.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=11.00m, EndMilepost=13.00m },
    new Site { RouteId="B", StartMilepost=13.00m, EndMilepost=14.00m },
  };

  var result = sites
    .GroupBy(item => item.RouteId)
    .Select(group => group
        // Required Here, since MySiteEqualityComparer breaks the rules
       .OrderBy(item => item.StartMilepost)  
       .GroupBy(item => item, new MySiteEqualityComparer())
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();

  // Let's have a look
  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(group => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                                 group.Select(g => string.Join("; ", g)))));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
A 0.00..1.00; A 1.00..2.00
A 5.00..7.00
B 3.00..5.00
B 11.00..13.00; B 13.00..14.00
```

Comment: Problem is you are relying on an implementation detail that may not generally be true (ie order of comparision, there is no reason to assume they will be compared in the oder you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of implementations where order of `Site`'s does not matter.  You can use the LINQ `Aggregate` function:

```
return sites.GroupBy(x => x.RouteId)
            .SelectMany(x =>
            {
                var groupedSites = new List<List<Site>>();
                var aggs = x.Aggregate(new List<Site>(), (contiguous, next) =>
                {
                    if (contiguous.Count == 0 || contiguous.Any(y => y.EndMilepost == next.StartMilepost))
                    {
                        contiguous.Add(next);
                    }
                    else if (groupedSites.Any(y => y.Any(z => z.EndMilepost == next.StartMilepost)))
                    {
                        var groupMatchIndex = groupedSites.FindIndex(y => y.Any(z => z.EndMilepost == next.StartMilepost));
                        var el = groupedSites.ElementAt(groupMatchIndex);
                        el.Add(next);
                        groupedSites[groupMatchIndex] = el;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        groupedSites.Add(contiguous);
                        contiguous = new List<Site>();
                        contiguous.Add(next);
                    }
                    return contiguous;
                }, final => { groupedSites.Add(final); return final; });
                return groupedSites;
            });
```

Alternatively, just with `foreach`:

```
return sites.GroupBy(x => x.RouteId)
            .SelectMany(x =>
            {
                var groupedSites = new List<List<Site>>();
                var aggList = new List<Site>();
                foreach (var item in x)
                {
                    if (aggList.Count == 0 || aggList.Any(y => y.EndMilepost == item.StartMilepost))
                    {
                        aggList.Add(item);
                        continue;
                    }

                    var groupMatchIndex = groupedSites.FindIndex(y => y.Any(z => z.EndMilepost == item.StartMilepost));
                    if (groupMatchIndex > -1)
                    {
                        var el = groupedSites.ElementAt(groupMatchIndex);
                        el.Add(item);
                        groupedSites[groupMatchIndex] = el;
                        continue;
                    }

                    groupedSites.Add(aggList);
                    aggList = new List<Site>();
                    aggList.Add(item);
                }

                groupedSites.Add(aggList);
                return groupedSites;
            });
```

Comment: Yeh, I guess I could have just done this, lol.

I was trying to see if there was any clever/efficient things I could come up with. I'm wondering if pre-sorting using built in methods, and assuming order, would be more efficient than using Any multiple times?

Comment: Probably :) I was just looking for an excuse to use the `Aggregate` function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method for grouping lists of the specific class (`Site`). It is implemented with an inner iterator function `GetGroup` that produces one group with adjacent sites. This function is called in a `while` loop to produce all groups.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Site>> GroupAdjacent(
    this IEnumerable<Site> source)
{
    var ordered = source
        .OrderBy(item => item.RouteId)
        .ThenBy(item => item.StartMilepost);
    IEnumerator<Site> enumerator;
    bool finished = false;
    Site current = null;
    using (enumerator = ordered.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (!finished)
        {
            yield return GetGroup();
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<Site> GetGroup()
    {
        if (current != null) yield return current;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var previous = current;
            current = enumerator.Current;
            if (previous != null)
            {
                if (current.RouteId != previous.RouteId) yield break;
                if (current.StartMilepost != previous.EndMilepost) yield break;
            }
            yield return current;
        }
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var allGroups = sites.GroupAdjacent();
foreach (var group in allGroups)
{
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

> A 0,00..1,00
>   A 1,00..2,00
>
> A 5,00..7,00
>
> B 3,00..5,00
>
> B 11,00..13,00
>   B 13,00..14,00